# std::move with std::shared_ptr in lambda

Tags: c++11, lambda, c++14, shared-ptr, move

I have a strange issue when moving `std::shared_ptr`s in lambdas. I am not sure if it is a bug or not, as I can reproduce with g++ v6.3 and clang++ v3.9.

When I compile and run the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

void f(std::shared_ptr<int> ptr) {
  std::cout << 3 << " " << ptr.get() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  auto ptr = std::make_shared<int>(42);
  std::cout << 1 << " " << ptr.get() << std::endl;
#ifdef LAMBDA
  auto lambda = [ptr]() {
#endif
    f(std::move(ptr));
    std::cout << 2 << " " << ptr.get() << std::endl;
#ifdef LAMBDA
  };
  lambda();
#endif
}
```

with the command `c++ -std=c++14 -o test main.cpp && ./test` yields something like

```
1 0x55a49e601c30 1
3 0x55a49e601c30 1
2 0 0
```

However, changing the compilation command to `c++ -std=c++14 -o test main.cpp -DLAMBDA` makes the execution print something I cannot explain:

```
1 0x55a49e601c30 1
3 0x55a49e601c30 3
2 0x55a49e601c30 2
```

So, it appears that the `std::move(move)`, when performed inside a lambda, does not actually cause the `shared_ptr` to be moved, nor does it prevent its reference counter to be incremented.

Again, I can reproduce this with clang++ and g++.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The captured variable `ptr` in a lambda is by default const, i.e. the type of `ptr` is `const std::shared_ptr<int>`.

`std::move` cannot move out const objects, so a copy is created instead.

If you really want to move it, the `ptr` must be allowed to be mutable:

```
auto lambda = [ptr]() mutable {
//                    ^~~~~~~
```

Comment: Thank you, I have completely overlooked the const nature of the captures! I have it working now.

Comment: it's also worth noting the standard doesn't put any limits on the value of a moved from shared_ptr except that it is valid, so even if it did use the move constructor both above outputs are still reasonable.

Saying that, it does say in the shared_ptr move constructor that the moved from shared_ptrs ptr is null and get() must get the ptr. So actually this isn't true.

Comment: *std::move cannot move out const objects* is not technically correct, you can "move" out a `const` object `X` if you declare a move ctor as `X(const X&&);`. Why would one want to do something as insane as that I don't know, but it is technically possible: live example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be6915b8c23d6736).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move captured `ptr` in lambda you need to capture it by reference, as follows:

```
auto lambda = [&ptr]() {
```

If you want to move `ptr` copy that belongs to lambda you have to follow kennytm answer.

Comment: Please explain the downvoting reason?

Comment: This statement has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: It has. Check program output with `ptr` captured by reference.
Has same result as allowing modification of parameters captured by copy.

Comment: The Question is asking why the move became a copy in C++14, your answer doesn't explain that. Not to mention it suggests not modifying capture data by taking it by reference and modifying through the reference, this is like saying you should pass const pointers to non const data to avoid modifying passed data instead of specifying the data as non const. At worst it's unsafe and at best it fragments your cache with erroneous dereferencing. It's simply not correct.