# Why is the copy constructor invoked in a lambda while moving a `unique_ptr`?

Tags: c++, lambda, unique-ptr

Why does this code fail to compile?

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

int foo() {
    auto num = std::make_unique<int>(1);
    auto func = [s = std::move(num)] {
        auto u = std::move(s); <-- ERROR!
        return *u;
    };
    return func();
}
```

The error is:

```
<source>:8:14: error: call to deleted constructor of 'std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int>>'
        auto u = std::move(s);
             ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../include/c++/10.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:468:7: note: 'unique_ptr' has been explicitly marked deleted here
      unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
```

I can't figure out why is the copy constructor being called, which is obviously deleted for a `unique_ptr` by design. I can understand *what* the error is, but not *why* it's there in the first place.

Here's what I think happens but I'm not sure. If I unpack this lambda into a sort of `struct` with the `operator()` as

```
template <typename T>
struct Lambda{
  :
  :
  operator() const{
    auto u = std::move(s); // <-- error
  }
  private:
  std::unique_ptr<T> s;
};
```

I think this would fail to compile because the `move(s)` would change the value of `s` which isn't allowed in a `const` function. So compilations should've failed citing the immutability of the lamda. Even the fix to this error is by changing the lambda to be `mutable`. But another one appears to be to make `s` a `shared_ptr` (which as per me should have failed since the lambda would still be immutable) and this is where I'm confused.

I've tried this on both `clang` and `gcc` with similar results. So, can please someone help with clearing the gap in my understanding?

Comment: Lambda captures, like `s` are const by default. Try adding `mutable` before `{`. (Also your lambda is missing an argument list?)

Comment: No argument list [works](https://godbolt.org/z/vYK7bG) as parameter list is optional as per the 4th avatar [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and I've tried adding `mutable` to the lambda which does fix it, as already mentioned in my question. I was more intent on deciphering the compiler error. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ok, if the answer below is insufficient, let us know and we'll clarify further.

Comment: @rustyx I have accepted the answer. The alternative of using a `shared_ptr` came with its own behavior. I've updated my comments to the answer below. Please do add if you have something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are trying to move a data member in a `const` member function.

The type and category of `std::move(s)` is `const unique_ptr&&`. There is no overload `unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&&)`, the only one that is viable is `unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&)`.

> I think this would fail to compile because the `move(s)` would change the value of `s` which isn't allowed in a `const` function.

No, `move` is simply a `static_cast`.

Comment: I understand the first part of your answer quite well. Regarding the `move`, what I meant was something on the lines of [this](https://godbolt.org/z/MxnTMK). As you see, `num` is changed during lambda construction and becomes null. Similarly `s` too should've become `null`, isn't it, akin to `num` as per constructor #10 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)?

Comment: I think this is probably a different question from the original one and is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319352/stdmove-with-stdshared-ptr-in-lambda) so in my case, `s` isn't actually modified, and hence the code compiles without a `mutable` keyword.

Comment: It's the move constructor that set's `s` null, not the `move` call

Comment: Ok. So just to clarify that I do understand what you are saying, `std::move` is just a simple cast that gives an rvalue reference to that object. The actual nullifying is done in the move constructor of the object that's being created using this rvalue reference which just moves the incoming object's memory.

Comment: Yes, that's correct